# Mac OS X 10.6.3 installation media

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I bought the following DVD from Apple: [Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard).

The box that was delivered is as pictured in the link above (inserted here for convenience).

[image]

The sealed package contains one DVD pictured below:

[image]

The directory listing is as follows:

```
$ ls -l
total 830
-r--r--r-- 1 unknown 197121     27 Mar 31  2010 autorun.inf
drwxr-xr-x 1 unknown 197121      0 Mar 31  2010 'Boot Camp'/
-r--r--r-- 1 unknown 197121 296497 Feb 26  2010 'Boot Camp Installation & Setup Guide.pdf'
drwxr-xr-x 1 unknown 197121      0 Mar 31  2010 DVDCDSharing/
-r--r--r-- 1 unknown 197121   1786 Feb 26  2010 'Read Me.rtf'
-r-xr-xr-x 1 unknown 197121 548664 Mar 31  2010 setup.exe*
```

This is not what I expected. I expected installation media - but what I got is something called Boot Camp. Should I return this to Apple? Anyone know how I use this Boot Camp to install Snow Leopard?

Comment: Did you insert the DVD into a Mac running OSX or into another system?

Comment: I inserted into a windows machine

Comment: What your received is indeed a Mac OS X Snow Leopard Install DVD, which is for Apple-branded hardware that supports that version of Mac OS X, **not** general PC hardware running Windows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows up as BootCamp because it assumes you are in a Windows environment on a Mac (for installing the drivers for your hardware after a BootCamp install); the OSX DVD's OSX Install portion/partition isn't meant to be read on Windows.

If you want to check the installer stuff, please run it on a Mac with OSX.

Comment: Ah got ya - I assumed Universal Disk Format (UDF) used on DVDs was standard and readable from all OSes.